# how to use nix::mount::mount() replace with libc::mount() in Rust

Tags: rust, ffi

I want to use the 'nix' library to replace with 'libc' in Rust FFI .

I want to use nix::mount::mount() to replace with libc::mount(). Now I have the followed code :

```rust
libc::mount(ptr::null(), path.as_ptr(), ptr::null(), libc:: MS_SLAVE, ptr::null())
```

I just want to know how to replace the ptr::null() in nix library, I try to use 'None' to do it, but failed. Please help me, thanks.

Show the error:

```
39 |     nix::mount::mount(
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type for type parameter `P1` declared on the function `mount`
   | 
  ::: /root/.cargo/registry/src/mirrors.ustc.edu.cn-15f9db60536bad60/nix-0.19.0/src/mount.rs:57:27
   |
57 | pub fn mount<P1: ?Sized + NixPath, P2: ?Sized + NixPath, P3: ?Sized + NixPath, P4: ?Sized + NixPath>(
   |                           ------- required by this bound in `nix::mount::mount`
   |
   = note: cannot satisfy `_: nix::NixPath`
```

Comment: Could you include what you tried and what error you got?

Comment: OK. I have done it.

Answer (score 2):

[`nix::mount::mount`](https://docs.rs/nix/0.19.0/nix/mount/fn.mount.html) has the function signature:

```rust
pub fn mount<P1: ?Sized + NixPath, P2: ?Sized + NixPath, P3: ?Sized + NixPath, P4: ?Sized + NixPath>(
    source: Option<&P1>, 
    target: &P2, 
    fstype: Option<&P3>, 
    flags: MsFlags, 
    data: Option<&P4>
) -> Result<()>
```

As you can see, the arguments `source`, `fstype` and `data` take options of generic type parameter. If you pass in `Some(value)`, these type parameters can be inferred based on the type of `value`, but if you pass in `None`, the compiler doesn't have enough information to infer a type for these parameters.

You can explicitly specify the type of the parameters to be some type that implements [`NixPath`](https://docs.rs/nix/0.19.0/nix/trait.NixPath.html), such as [`Path`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/path/struct.Path.html):

```rust
nix::mount::mount<Path, Path, Path, Path>(None, path, None, MsFlags::MS_SLAVE, None)
```

Or you can specify a type parameter directly on `None`:

```rust
nix::mount::mount(None::<Path>, path, None::<Path>, MsFlags::MS_SLAVE, None::<Path>)
```

Comment: Yes, I put it in a turbofish and solve my problem. Thanks so much.