# Mounting a filesystem

Tags: linux, rust, filesystems, mount

Is there a way to mount a device (e.g. `/dev/sda1`) or a temporary filesystem (e.g. `procfs` or `devtmpfs`) in Rust? I would preferably like to autodetect the filesystem type if possible. I'd like to also be able to change the mount options, but also be able to fall back to default mount options if none are specified. It doesn't have to be platform-agnostic, I'd just like it to work on Linux with little or no dependencies.

Comment: well, there is the `mount()` system call, I'm sure there are bindings for rust that allow you to use it.

Comment: Would using `std::process::Command` to invoke the `mount` command fit your use case? Seems to be the simplest solution, and doesn't require any dependency.

Comment: See also [how to use nix::mount::mount() replace with libc::mount() in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64693079/how-to-use-nixmountmount-replace-with-libcmount-in-rust).

Comment: @SvenMarnach I've already looked at that. I wasn't able to get any sense out of it.

Comment: @SirDarius I'd prefer to not require external commands.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up doing this:

```rs
fn mount_md(source: Option<&str>, target: &str, fstype: Option<&str>, flags: MsFlags, data: Option<&str>) -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    std::fs::create_dir_all(target)?;
    nix::mount::mount::<str, str, str, str>(source, target, fstype, flags, data)?;
    Ok(())
}

mount_md(Some("proc"), "proc", Some("proc"), nix::mount::MsFlags::MS_NOSUID | nix::mount::MsFlags::MS_NOEXEC | nix::mount::MsFlags::MS_NODEV, None)?;
```